# Android Studio: crash when initialising ImageButton

Tags: android, image, button, crash, imagebutton

I am trying to open a new activity by clicking on an imagebutton. I placed the imagebutton and tried to make an onclick method for it. The app already crashes on the place where I try to find my button.It does print the first Log but that's it. It doesn't even get to the onClick method. I am very new to android so I have very little experience working with it.

```
public class Bestellingen extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private ArrayList<String> elementen;
    private ListView lV;
    private MenuAdapter mA;


    ImageView image;
    Spinner spinner1;
    ImageButton imageButtonWinkelmand;

    public Bestellingen() {
        Log.d("tag","test");
        imageButtonWinkelmand = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageWinkelmand);  // here
        Log.d("testje","erna");
}
```

My onClick method

```
   imageButtonWinkelmand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("in de onclick","test");
                startActivity(new Intent(Bestellingen.this, BestellingenInfo.class));
            }
        });
```

and I did make it in the activity_main.xml

```
<ImageButton

    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:id="@+id/imageWinkelmand"
    android:src="@drawable/winkelmand"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:contentDescription="winkelmandje"/>
```

Chat Conversation End

Comment: Post your logcat here.

Comment: call this in your oncreate section `imageButtonWinkelmand = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageWinkelmand);`

Comment: Putting it in onCreate() worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override **onCreate()** and find views inside **onCreate()**.

```
ImageButton imageButtonWinkelmand;
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            // Find your views in onCreate();
            imageButtonWinkelmand = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageWinkelmand); 

    }
```

Use like this.

Comment: I can't yet, need to wait 10 mins

Answer (score 1):

Remove `Bestellingen` method at first .

Then call `ImageButton` in your **oncreate()** section

`imageButtonWinkelmand = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageWinkelmand);`

**Finally**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        setContentView(R.layout.Your_layout_name);
        imageButtonWinkelmand = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageWinkelmand);
```

Comment: @LievenLuyckx Glad to hear .Move ahead .

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageButton imageButton;
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            // Find your views in onCreate();
            imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageWinkelmand); 

    }
```